# PHP preg_replace help trim special characters

Tags: php, regex, trim

I tried to search around but couldn't find anything useful. I need to trim special characters from beginning and end of a string and identify if the remaining portion is a number.

For example

```
(5)
[[12]]
{3}
#!8(#
!255=
/879/
```

I need a `preg_match` expression for it. The regular expression should ignore the string if any alphabets come in between.

Comment: In other words, you just need to extract number from string, right? If that is the case, `\d+` will help you

Comment: not really. because strings can be alphanumeric and in that case, i dont need to extract the number - that would be a valid string for me but all above cases are invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string="yourstring";
$new_string=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $string);
if(is_numeric($new_string){
    echo "number";
} else {
    echo "string";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?!.*[a-zA-Z])\W*(\d+)\W*$
```

You can use this.`Lookahead` will validate if only numbers are there.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cT0hV4/2

Comment: sure, i will. it is asking me to wait for another 6 more before i can accept it as an answer :)

Comment: @Ahmad you asked for an regex which ignores string with alphabets...but the answer you accepted replaces all?????